# CORS Missing 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: asp.net, fetch-api, webapi, ocelot

I'm trying to do a typescript fetch and got some troubles with CORS.

1. FROM http://localhost:3000 (solidjs web app)
2. THROUGH https://localhost:6331 (Ocelot gateway)
3. TO http://localhost:1339 (asp.net webapi)

Although I set up the CORS (with 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin') in my webapi project, I have the error

> Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:6331/what/ever' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**WEB API:**

```
app.MapMethods("/api/v1/what/ever", new[] { "OPTIONS" }, (HttpContext context) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000"); 
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, POST"); 
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type"); 
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400"); 
    return Results.Ok();
});
```

**Gateway**

```
{
   "GlobalConfiguration": {
      "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:6331"
   },
   "Routes": [
       {
           "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/v1/what/ever",
           "DownstreamScheme": "http",
           "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
               {
                   "Host": "host.docker.internal",
                   "Port": "1339"
                }
           ],
           "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/what/ever",
           "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "POST", "OPTIONS" ]
       }
   ]
}
```

**SolidJs Web App**

```
const response = await fetch("https://localhost:6331/what/ever", {
    method: 'POST',
    cache: "no-cache",
    body: JSON.stringify(dataToSubmit),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
});
```

The request arrives at the webapi and is executed there, but there is no response returned. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Is this Ocelot gateway including the headers in its responses to the client?

Answer (score 1):

I used your code on a similar configuration, without docker.

Using your `app.MapMethods` it does not work.
But it does when i add POST in addition to "OPTIONS" (used by preflight request) lke this:

```cs
app.MapMethods("/api/v1/what/ever", new[] { "OPTIONS", "POST" }, (HttpContext context) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000"); 
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, POST"); 
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type"); 
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400"); 
context.Response.Headers.Add("tuo-path", $"->{context.Request.Path}<-"); 
    context.Response.Headers.Add("tuo-host", $"->{context.Request.Headers.Host}<-"); 
    context.Response.Headers.Add("tuo-origin", $"->{context.Request.Headers.Origin}<-"); 
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
    
    return Results.Ok( new{ io = "sono qui"});
});
```

You should try this at first.

Furthermore, i added 2 headers, with some information about the request headers and the path, to check what is really sent to the webapi: that information is returned even when you have a failing preflight.

To force the fail, you can set 3001 as port value in **webapi** map method.

[image: Failing request]

With port 3000 in webapi checked that works if i call the **webapi** directly from the browser `localhost:3000`, or if i call **ocelot -> webapi** (changing the ports an paths, naturally).

For this purpose a used your simple vanilla js fetch.

[image: Successfull request]

Both was running in my machine, i don't know if you are using running container with compose or something else.
However i thing this should work for you.

Hope it helps!

Cose belle!

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but nevertheless it put me on the right track. Thanks for that. +1

Answer (score 0):

Seems like everything was ok, except the gateway CORS:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(setup =>
{
    setup.AddDefaultPolicy(policy =>
    { 
        policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowCredentials();
    });
});
```

and

```
app.UseCors();
```